# Cannot test purchase from iTunes store, getting two seemingly conflicting errors

Tags: iphone, ios, in-app-purchase

I've created a test iTunes user, logged out of the iTunes user on my iPhone and have left it blank (i.e. not logged in) and I've attempted to purchase a product which is ready for sale and available but I get two errors when I attempt to make the purchase:

> 2012-02-05 14:25:09.875 storm[4175:707] StoreKit: in the process of
>   purchasing 2012-02-05 14:25:13.138 storm[4175:707] StoreKit: invalid
>   productIdentifier: DisableAds total productsReceived: 0   (Filename:
>   /Applications/buildAgent/work/b0bcff80449a48aa/Runtime/ExportGenerated/iPhonePlayer-armv7/UnityEngineDebug.cpp
>   Line: 39)
>
> 2012-02-05 14:25:13.658 storm[4175:707] StoreKit: error: Cannot
>   connect to iTunes Store purchase failed with error: Cannot connect to
>   iTunes Store   (Filename:
>   /Applications/buildAgent/work/b0bcff80449a48aa/Runtime/ExportGenerated/iPhonePlayer-armv7/UnityEngineDebug.cpp
>   Line: 39)
>
> -> applicationDidResignActive()
>   -> applicationDidEnterBackground()

It says both the purchase does not exist and that it couldn't connect to the store, if it couldn't connect to the store how could it verify the item exists? That scares me a little.

Ive looked at various troubleshooting tips online but none seem to apply to me.

So any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this an update to an app? If so you may need to delete it, then build/run from Xcode. (I.e. remove the instance the the app received from the store)

Comment: Deleting the app from the phone then installing it again fixed it, so your answer would have worked in solving my problem :)